# spring-kafka Multiple @KafkaListener with different Json objects not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am having one factory which is common for my four different @KafkaListers, and each listener is expected to consume its own respective JSON Object from its respective topic. I cant get it working as i get exception which says  :
he class 'com.abc.MyObject' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*). Even after i add below, i still get the same exception:
config.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "");
if i dont use the generic factory and  use it with one specific Object, it works fine for that object, but that way i will have to create four factories for four different Kafkalisteners.

My Kafka listers:

```
@KafkaListener( topics="number_1_event", groupId="abc-group", containerFactory="kafkaABCListenerContainerFactory")
public void consumeMyMessage(MyTopic1Class data, @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_PARTITION_ID) int partitionId,
            @Header(KafkaHeaders.OFFSET) int offsetId) {
                // code here
            }



@KafkaListener( topics="number_2_event", groupId="abc2-group", containerFactory="kafkaABCListenerContainerFactory")
/* Similar method signature here*/

@KafkaListener( topics="number_3_event", groupId="abc3-group", containerFactory="kafkaABCListenerContainerFactory")

@KafkaListener( topics="number_4_event", groupId="abc4-group", containerFactory="kafkaABCListenerContainerFactory")
```

Config :

```
@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> abcdConsumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> config = new HashMap<>();

    config.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
            config.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    config.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, JsonDeserializer.class);
    config.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");


    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(config, new StringDeserializer(),
            new JsonDeserializer<>(Object.class));
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaABCListenerContainerFactory() { 
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();      
    factory.setConsumerFactory(abcdConsumerFactory());

    return factory;
    }
```

I am currently using above configs and i get the trust package error as i mentioned above. **If i replace Object in the above configs with MyTopic1Class, or MyTopic2Class,** and then run it it will work for that particular object just fine.
    Please help !!

Comment: Can you provide some more context as well as which version you are using? We automatically trust the package of the inferred type from the signature ( in this case, `MyTopic1Class`). Where does `com.abc.MyObject` come into play?

Comment: Sorry, That would be com.abc.MyTopic1Class instead of com.abc.MyObject. I am using spring-kafka 2.3.5.RELEASE with spring boot 2.2.4.RELEASE.  If i use the above factory after replacing Object with one of the json object MyTopic1Class for number_1_event topic, it will work fine. But when i use just Object instead of a specifc Object  so all 4 different Topics with their different classes can use same factory, it doesn't work and gives the trust error. I am testing in my eclipse IDE by running it as a Sprint boot app

Comment: But why do you want to change the signature to just receive `Object` instead of `MyTopic1Class`? The factory can be `<String, Object>` and your listeners can received narrower types than `Object` at runtime because of type erasure.

Comment: Do you mean that i can just use ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyTopic1Class> and  ConsumerFactory<String, MyTopic1Class> abcdConsumerFactory(). and this factory signature would work for when my number_1_event topic receives a MyTopic1Class. Will it work when topic number_2_event receives MyTopic2Class and using the same factory signature

Answer (score 0):

> Do you mean that i can just use `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, MyTopic1Class>` and `ConsumerFactory<String, MyTopic1Class> abcdConsumerFactory()`. and this factory signature would work for when my number_1_event topic receives a MyTopic1Class. Will it work when topic number_2_event receives MyTopic2Class and using the same factory signature

Yes, it will work, but it's cleaner to use

```
ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> abcdContainerFactory()
ConsumerFactory<String, Object> abcdConsumerFactory()
```

Your listeners can consumer the narrower types `MyTopic1Class`, `MyTopic2Class` etc.

The generic types on the factories are compile-time only; they are erased at runtime.

Comment: Ok, Thanks. But when i use it this way, i get the trust package error : he class 'com.abc.MyTopic1Class' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*). MyTopic1Class is in a different maven module, would that matter ? i cant get past this error..

Comment: If you can reproduce it with a complete, verifiable small project, I can take a look. In the meantime, try adding `properties = { "spring.json.value.default.type=com.abc.MyTopic1Class", "spring.json.use.type.headers=false" }` to each `@KafkaListener` (with the right class in each case).

Comment: Tried it. Getting same error after i added your recommendations: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error deserializing key/value for partition number_1_event-0 at offset 30.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The class 'com.abc.MyTopic1Class' is not in the trusted packages: [java.util, java.lang]. If you believe this class is safe to deserialize, please provide its name. If the serialization is only done by a trusted source, you can also enable trust all (*).
 at DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.getClassIdType(DefaultJackson2JavaTypeMapper.java:125)

Comment: Sorry; there must be something else going on with your application that I am not seeing; I need a simple version of it to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: I don't want your whole project; it is probably to involved; I need a small version that reproduces the issue; you can share it on GitHub or a GitHub Gist.